# How to cut a 1 inch thick 12x48 plank in half (thickness)?

Tags: woodworking, cutting

I was wondering how you would go about doing this. I have a 48x12x1 Bamboo blank. I'd like to cut the thickness in half so I have 2 planks. Perfect 0.5 width (with blade) does not matter as long as it's cut in half.

My first thought was to square up the 12" high plank on a table saw and use blade 6-8" high, then cut and flip then planer? Do table saw blades even go that high?

There's a Woodworking club nearby I could use. If I can't do it myself, I can ask one of the guys, but I'd like to give this a go.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ask one of the guys, and use the event for learning, for the next time you have a need like this. I think you would be much happier with the results.

Comment: Tx Turner's answer is good. You may want to ask at [Woodworking.SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) for additional ideas/tips.

Comment: Thanks! I got this bamboo at a great price, but it was too heavy for my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like what you're after is resawing-- which is typically done on a band saw with a wide blade. Then you have to clean up the saw marks, which does take some thickness away. So you may end up with two 3/8" pieces rather than 1/2".

Comment: Even the saw blade is going to take away resultant thickness.

Comment: 3/8 would be fine. Heck, 1/4 would still work for this hard wood. Excellent info for future reference! Thanks